# How to identifiy driver causing problems at boot time?

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, live-usb

My Ubuntu live USB hangs on boot. I suspect a driver is causing the hang. How can I identify which driver actually causes the freeze?

Here are the details:

1. During boot I press F12 and select USB storage, when Ubuntu screen shows I select "try before installing" and the screen goes blank with blinking cursor in the left-top corner. Neither ctrl-alt-del nor power-off works. I need to hard power off the machine by holding the power button.
2. During boot I press F12 and select USB storage, when Ubuntu screen shows I press F6 and mark `acpi=off`, `noapic`, `edd=on`, `nodmraid` and `nomodeset` options, then I edit boot line by removing `quiet` `splash` and adding `no_console_suspend` `initcall_debug` options and press enter. Ubuntu boots but at certain point hangs with kernel panic messages. Neither ctrl-alt-del nor power-off works. I need to hard power off the machine by keeping power-off button for a few seconds.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Kernel panic @Ubuntu boot - screenshot]
[image: Kernel panic @Ubuntu boot - screenshot]

Is there any way I can identify which drivers that are being loaded to tell which driver causes the hang and possibly disable it?

Comment: tricky, but try changing your boot parameters from "quiet splash" to "no_console_suspend initcall_debug" to see more info

Comment: Please post the exact messages (the kernel panic stuff) you see. You can also upload a photo of your screen instead of typing.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Too see more of the panic message, one could change the console resolution using the kernel parameter "vga=0x0f01" or "vga=0x0f07"